# Is the probability $\frac12$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $n$ players in total. Note that $n$ is even. We want to pick $\frac n2$ players uniformly at random. We have access to only one unbiased coin. We want to make this bisection in minimum expected number of coin tosses. What should I do?

My approach: I will keep tossing-if it is H I will add the player to team A else to team B. If there are already $\frac n2$ players in any team, I stop tossing and put the rest in other team. Leaving aside the problem of proving why this will give minimum number of tosses, I am not sure why the players have equal probability of getting to team A or B. It is clear for the first $\frac n2$ players but after that it gets a little messy.

Please don't say that it is symmetric so probability is half trivially.

Comment: But... it is symmetric.

Comment: Not following your method.  If you imagine that the players are in a line and that you are tossing the coin sequentially down the line, then there is a high probability that the last two players are assigned to the same team, so your method is non-uniform.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you imagine that you can "shuffle" the players before you start flipping the coin then there is no need to flip the coin at all.  Just shuffle and take the first $\frac n2$ for team $A$.

Comment: @lulu I only have a coin. I can't shuffle randomly

Comment: To get random numbers from $1$ to $n$ (which is what we need), just generate $k$-bit numbers using the coin with sufficient large $k$ and ignore the sequences giving a number larger than $n$ or $0$.

Comment: Right, then your method is non-uniform for the reason I said.

Comment: So I already have someone claiming that its symmetric and another person saying that its not uniform. @JohnDoe Still think your comment is true?

Comment: Of course it is symmetric!  All that means is that each person has the same probability of being assigned to either team.  Alas, that is not the same as uniformity.  In uniform assignment, the last two players should be assigned independently, but your method fails that test.

Comment: @Peter You are forgetting the part where I want to minimze the number of coin tosses

Comment: @user505050 It can be symmetric and non-uniform as well. As lulu says, the last two people are highly likely to be on the same team - but what team that is is still 50-50. So it is both symmetric and non-uniform.

Comment: @user505050 All you can do is stopping when it is clear that the number will exceed $n$.

Comment: Do you mean expected number of coin tosses is a minimum?

Comment: With $n=4$ the six possible deciding outcomes are $00, 010, 011, 11, 101,110$. The 1st and 4th occur with probability ${1 \over 4}$ the others with probability ${1 \over 8}$.

Comment: Yes you guys are right...it should be expected

Comment: You are asking two questions here. The answer section is now very confusing as most seem not to be addressing the question you have in the title.

Comment: I'm just wandering in from the "hot network questions", and have to say upfront I do not really grasp the math here. It occurs to me if you break n into pairs of two you could use one flip to assign 2 at once, so you can do it in n/2 flips.  Flip of H assigns 1st in pair to Team A, thus 2nd in the Pair is automatically assigned to Team B, and vice-versa. Note - I don't know enough to know if this addresses your actual question, so I'm not attempting an answer.

Comment: @CameronRoberts If you didn't care about uniformity, only that each player has probability $1/2$ of getting in team A, then you could just assign the players into two teams however you wish and flip a coin to decide which one is called "A".

Comment: @copper.hat: I think you made a mistake. Should that last one be 100 rather than 110 or am I misunderstanding your notation?

Comment: @chris: Yes! Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 11):

Step 1: Set $k={n\choose n/2}$.

Step 2: Choose an integer between $1$ and $k$, uniformly at random with your coin.  This is a well-known problem, e.g. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/570).  If $k$ happens to be a power of $2$ it can be done in a finite number of flips; otherwise, either the number of flips is unbounded (but very unlikely to be large) or your distribution is not precisely uniform (but very close).

Step 3: Choose the subset of size $n/2$, based on the outcome of step 2, and a lexicographic ordering of the subsets.  For example, if $n=4$ and the players are $A,B,C,D$, then the first subset is $AB$, the second is $AC$, etc.

Comment: Note that pure rejection, although it is the most straightforward method, is not strictly speaking necessary. You can use entropy-preserving techniques. For example, if you partition the interval $[0,1]$ into $k$ equal length subintervals, each coin flip generates a bit  in the binary expansion of a uniform random number on $[0,1]$. After n flips, the most that could happen to the number in all subsequent flips is that it increases by $2^{-n}$. If the current number say $x$ and $x+2^{-n}$ are in the same subinterval, then you're done, otherwise you continue.

Comment: @Ian, this is the basis for the second-rated solution of the link I provided.

Answer (score 7):

It can't be done with a finite number of tosses at all. If $n=4$, then there are $\binom42=6$ possible bisections, so you want the probability of each bisection to be $\frac16$, which is not a sum of powers of $\frac12$.

You *could* consider a protocol using an unbounded number of tosses, and then ask for a protocol that minimizes the *expected* number of tosses. Or a protocol that maximizes the probability of being done as soon as possible, or something like that.

Comment: While it seems plausible, how do you prove that it cannot be done with a finite number of tosses (as opposed to a fixed number depending only on $n$)? The number of tosses may be finite but unbounded.

Comment: Oh, I really meant that it can't be done in a fixed number of tosses. It can (almost surely) be done after finitely many tosses with an unbounded algorithm.

Comment: @ChrisCulter "It can't be done with a finite number of tosses" is trivially not true, strictly speaking. Indeed the number of unbiased coin tosses required to generate a random number between 1 and k *exactly* uniformly is an a.s. finite random variable. But since that is obvious, it's not hard to understand that you meant to say that you can't be guaranteed to be done with probability 1 within any fixed finite number of tosses. I think copper.hat is asking how you can prove that latter statement.

Comment: @Ian The probability of an event $E$ after $k$ tosses is $|E|/2^k$. If $|E|/2^k=1/6$ then $6|E|=2^k$, which is impossible since $2^k$ is not divisible by $3$.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Yes, that says that you can't flip the coin *exactly* $k$ times and generate a uniform number between $1$ and $n$ unless $2^k$ is divisible by $n$. That doesn't already imply that you can't flip the coin a random number of times that is at most $k$ in order to generate such a number. Can this "decide how many times to flip in finite time then flip that many times" procedure be encoded into a "flip a fixed number of times" procedure?

Comment: @Ian Flipping the coin at most $k$ times is equivalent to flipping it exactly $k$ times. Just keep flipping and ignore any results you don't need. Or for another argument, note that $1/6$ is not a sum of powers of $1/2$, which was stated in my answer. (That's because a sum of powers of $1/2$ still has the form $m/2^k$ for some positive integers $m$, $k$.)

Comment: I realise that it can be done in a finite number for almost all trials (using rejection for example), I was wondering if it was straightforward to show that there is no finite (and necessarily unbounded) way for **all** trials.

Comment: @copper.hat I guess I don't know what that means. Given some algorithm, let $p(x)$ be the probability of halting after $x$ trials. We can have $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x)=1$ (using rejection for example), although we can't have $p(x)=1$ for any $x$ (by my arguments). What other property of $p$ can we hope for?

Comment: @ChrisCulter: It s clear from your divisibility argument that there is no fixed number (depending on $n$) that will work. However, that does not preclude (at least to me) the existence of a mechanism that always terminates (not just as.)?

Comment: @copper.hat Are you asking whether there is a way to ensure that the number of flips is *surely* finite rather than merely *almost surely* finite? I think in principle such a map exists (in effect you just need a measure preserving bijection between one probability space and the same probability space minus some null set) but there is no reason to believe that it will be at all simple.

Comment: @copper.hat Let $U_x$ be the set of infinite sequences of flip results that force the mechanism to run for at least $x$ steps. My argument shows that every $U_x$ is nonempty. Are you hoping that $\cap_x U_x$ is empty?

Comment: @ChrisCulter: I am wondering if it is possible to have a causal mechanism that terminates for all coin flips and produces a uniform distribution. I presume not, but it is not immediately obvious to me how to prove it. (A non causal mechanism is straightforward, but useless.)

Comment: @ChrisCulter The obvious choices of procedures make $\bigcap_x U_x$ nonempty. However, every $U_x$ is nonempty by pure distributional considerations as you have shown. On the other hand, $\bigcap_x U_x$ has probability zero. So there is some question as to whether one can adjust the definition of your random variable to be restricted to *only* the finite sequences.

Comment: I am very curious about this. I may ask it as a separate question if I cannot find an answer soon.

Comment: @copper.hat Please do! I don't think I've addressed the question adequately -- I think e.g. it should be really easy to show that $\bigcap_x U_x$ is nonempty, but the reason somehow escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work this out fully for $n=4.$
We have at least two flips and no more than three, because by the time $n-1$ players have been placed on teams one team will be full and the last player's team will already be determined.
Let $X_1,$ $X_2,$ and $X_3$ (if needed) 
be the outcomes of the flips in that order.
We'll first consider the first two flips, and for each of those cases consider the remaining flip if we need to.

Case $X_1 = H, X_2 = H.$ Then players $1$ and $2$ go on team $A$ and the other players go on team $B$; the outcome is $AABB,$ with probability $\frac14.$

Case $X_1 = T, X_2 = T.$ Then players $1$ and $2$ go on team $B$ and the other players go on team $A$; the outcome is $BBAA,$ with probability $\frac14.$

Case $X_1 = H, X_2 = T.$ Then players $1$ and $2$ go on teams $A$ and $B,$ respectively, and we have to flip again. This produces two sub-cases:

- $X_1 = H, X_2 = T, X_3=H.$ The outcome is $ABAB,$ with probability $\frac18.$
- $X_1 = H, X_2 = T, X_3=T.$ The outcome is $ABBA,$ with probability $\frac18.$

Case $X_1 = T, X_2 = H.$ Then players $1$ and $2$ go on teams $B$ and $A,$ respectively, and we have to flip again. This produces two sub-cases:

- $X_1 = T, X_2 = H, X_3=H.$ The outcome is $BAAB,$ with probability $\frac18.$
- $X_1 = T, X_2 = H, X_3=T.$ The outcome is $BABA,$ with probability $\frac18.$

Observe that for player number $k,$ for any $k$ such that $1 \leq k \leq n,$
for every sequence of flips that places player $k$ on team $A$ there is another sequence of flips of the same length (and the same probability) that places player $k$ on team $B.$
Therefore player $k$ has equal probability (specifically, $\frac12$) to be on either team.
This is true in general for any $n,$ not just for $n=4.$

But notice that there are two outcomes ($AABB$ and $BBAA$) that place players $1$ and $2$ on the same team, and the event consisting of these two outcomes has probability $\frac12$;
whereas the outcomes that place players $2$ and $3$ on the same team
($BAAB$ and $ABBA$) constitute an event whose probability is $\frac14.$

The criterion about each player having $\frac12$ probability to be on either team is only a small part of what we think of as the uniformity of random selection of players for the teams.
After all, we can achieve the $\frac12$ probability just by flipping a single coin and assigning the outcome $AABB$ to heads and $BBAA$ to tails.
That's why I would prefer a uniform distribution over all $\binom{n}{n/2}$ possible lists of assignments, as discussed in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

To make the numbers integers, let 2k = n. If you've assigned a players to team A and b players to team B, then you have k-a left for team A and k-b left for team B. The next player should therefore have probability (k-a)/(2k-a-b) probability to be assigned to team A. The simplest method is to find the smallest p such that 2<sup>p</sup> >= 2k-a-b, flip the coin p times, convert the result to binary, assign to team A if the result is <= k-a, assign to team B if the result is between k-a+1 and 2k-a-b, and repeat otherwise. From there, there's the the low hanging fruit of dividing out by the gcd of k-a and k-b.

Further improvements, however, are more complicated. Suppose k=5. The first player can be assigned by a coin flip. The next should have a 4/9 chance for one team and 5/9 for the other. So you can flip the coin four times, convert to binary, and send them to one team for 1-4 and the other for 5-9. 10-16 will result in a repeat, so there are seven outcomes that are "wasted". But if you're unlucky enough to have to repeat, then there are 49 ways that can happen (7*7), and you can can split those 49 possibilities into five groups of 9 with 4 left over. So only those 4 are wasted. If you flip the coin four more times and get one of the 7 "wasted" possibilities, you can multiply that by the 4 wasted and get 28, which you can divide into three groups of 9 with 1 left over. And so on.